# How to get the second parameter of map from an apply method?

Tags: python, list, apply

I have the following dataset:

```
 data = {"C1":[[(3, 5), (6, 8), (9-10)], [(0, 2), (5, 7), (9, 10)], [], [(1, 11)], [(0, 7), (8, 10)], [(5, 6)], [(0, 1)]]}
dt = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(dt)
```

that looks like:

```
    0       [(3, 5), (6, 8), (9,10)]
    1       [(0, 2), (5, 7), (9, 10)]
    2       []
    3       [(1, 11)]
    4       [(0, 7), (8, 10)]
    5       [(5, 6)]
    6       [(0, 1)]
```

I want to get the length of each tuple (the second element of tuple minus the first element).

My favorite output is something like

```
0       [(3, 5), (6, 8), (9,10)]        [2,2,1]
1       [(0, 2), (5, 7), (9,10)]        [2,2,1]
2                         []            []
3                  [(1, 11)]            [10]
4          [(0, 7), (8, 10)]            [7,2]
5                   [(5, 6)]            [1]
6                   [(0, 1)]            [1]
```

I am currently using this code:

```
dt['C2] = dt['C1'].apply(list(map(lambda x: x[1]-x[0])))
```

It gives the following error:

```
map() must have at least two arguments
```

Since I am using the `apply` method, I expect the second parameter of `map` be automatically gotten from `apply`, why it is not happening?

Answer (score 2):

The lambda given to `.apply()` is applied to every row in the column, individually. So you can just throw a list comprehension in to do what you want:

```
data = {"C1":[[(3, 5), (6, 8), (9, 10)], [(0, 2), (5, 7), (9, 10)], [], [(1, 11)], [(0, 7), (8, 10)], [(5, 6)], [(0, 1)]]}
dt = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(dt)

>>> dt['C2'] = dt['C1'].apply(lambda lst: [tup[1] - tup[0] for tup in lst])
>>> dt
                          C1         C2
0  [(3, 5), (6, 8), (9, 10)]  [2, 2, 1]
1  [(0, 2), (5, 7), (9, 10)]  [2, 2, 1]
2                         []         []
3                  [(1, 11)]       [10]
4          [(0, 7), (8, 10)]     [7, 2]
5                   [(5, 6)]        [1]
6                   [(0, 1)]        [1]
```